# how to best take care of a xanthosoma sagittifolium?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, watering

A few months ago I bought a big beautiful xanthosoma sagittifolium. I have it situated by a northern facing window because I read it does not like full sun.

I'm very confused by this plant because it lost its big leaves a few weeks after I got it. It continuously grows new leaves which either turn yellow and die before opening, or die a few weeks after opening.

I've tried moving it around and varying how much water I give it. So my questions are: what does this plant like and how is its health? The original instructions I got with it don't seem to be working. Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: What size of pot is that? Do you realize this plant will grow to 12 feet high and 12 feet wide if it's in good conditions (outdoors in a suitable climate)? I think the poor thing just doesn't want to be a bonsai!

Comment: Is it in a pot inside that basket (or whatever it is)? and does  the pot have drainage holes? Is the same pot it was in when you bought it?

Comment: it's in its original plastic pot (with drainage holes) inside the basket. it is quite wide but i bought a bigger pot to repot it into